# UITextView just horizontal scrolling help

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextview

I have a UITextView , i want show its' text in horizontal, my UITextView has a static width

```
[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 161, 23)];
```

so when the length of UITextView's text is greater than 23, i need UITextView  horizontal scrolling , please help me...

Answer (score 1):

put this code 
after initializing

```
[txt setContentOffset:CGPointMake(give_high_value_here_than_content, y)];
```

Good luck

Comment: i just want scroll uitextview  in horizontal, but that sounds didn't work

Comment: You have to deal with xib file for set paging  enable as well as [txt contentSize:cgrectmake()]; and [txt  setContentStretch:(CGRect)];

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // We restrict the horizontal scrolling here.
    self.textView.contentSize = self.textView.frame.size;
}
```

Implement this text view delegate method.

Now when the characters entered becomes greater than 23, we set the content size of the text view to a higher value so that horizontal scrolling gets enabled automatically.

```
- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *) tView {
    if (tView.text.length > 23) {
// Set some higher width of the text view content size.
        tView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, tView.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> mscrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(180,30);
>   mscrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

Use this 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using interface builder then just check the property.

```
show horizontal scrolling.
```

by default this property is not enable

Comment: this is only for the scroll view. doesnt change the text's lineBreakMode