# Drawing text to a custom UIView in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` and a `UITableCell` subclass. I'd like each table cell to have a `UIScrollView` with a custom `UIView`. The custom `UIView` will include a series of `NSStrings` from an array. I'd like the `UIScrollView` to horizontally page-scroll through the `NSStrings` in the `UIView`.

I can't figure out how to implement the custom `UIView` and draw the text to the view.

It was a suggestion from someone on my previous post, that I should draw the strings onto a custom `UIView`, rather than use `UILabels`. [UITableView scrolling slow, memory leak issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669139/uitableview-scrolling-slow-memory-leak-issue/10669234#10669234)

I have referred to both Apple's TableViewSuite and AdvancedTableCell projects, but I cannot grasp how to implement for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use UITextView instead of UIView and UILabel if you don`t need editing you can turn it off using .editing property.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add text to the UITextView that can scroll horizontally by string?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263161/uitextview-just-horizontal-scrolling-help