# How can I make/program a UIlabel to scroll horizontally upon user input?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm making a simple calculator in iOS, and I want the user to be able to scroll the label horizontally when the end gets truncated.

How would I go about doing this? My original idea was to make two buttons that would move the label left or right by using stringpadtoLength type of method, but that seemed inefficient.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: You could set the truncation mode to head instead of tail ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways of building this.

1. Use a UITextView and always return `NO` from `-textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`. This should get you 90% the way there very fast.
2. Build a custom control using a `UIScrollView` which contains a `UILabel` that uses `-sizeToFit`. This will be a bit more work, but will do exactly what you expect.

Comment: I have made the textview, but how can I limit it to just horizontal scrolling? I don't want the calculations to be continued onto the next line of the text view, I want it to continue horizontally with the option to scroll left and right.

Comment: @user2329239 Make sure the text view is set for horizontal scrolling, then adjust the width on `-textViewDidChange:` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263161/uitextview-just-horizontal-scrolling-help)

Answer (score 1):

I went for Jefferey's second suggestion because I thought it would give a "cleaner" result. Turns out, it's not that easy to implement. Here's what you have to be careful about when you're putting a single-line `UILabel` inside of `UIScrollView`, in order to be able to scroll horizontally through the text.

- The parent `UIViewController` should have the box "Adjust scroll view
  insets" unchecked. If you forget this your text may be placed below the content of the `UIScrollView`, meaning that you can only see it if you hold it while over-scrolling down.
- Call `[self.toolboxItemNameLabel sizeToFit];` in your `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` in order to set the right size for your `UILabel`. This ensures that the scrolling is comfortable, going from the left to the right of the text.
- When using autolayout, you must add constraints for the leading and trailing space to container of the `UILabel` which is inside of the `UIScrollView`. Thanks to [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21274089) for the answer.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the tips. After reading your other post, I still have an issue where my label now scrolls but does not scroll to the end of the text content. Am I missing anything obvious?